# Rspec: test number of rows in CSV output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, rspec

In Rspec how do I test the number of rows that are in a CSV file?

I have created a CSV file in a mutation. I am able to test the output of the CSV by checking if certain text is included. However, I would like to be able to test the number of rows that are in the output.

Please find an *example* of what I have tested so far below which passes:

```
describe "#execute" do

    it "creates a CSV for the specified content" do
      outcome = mutation.run(mutation_params)

      expect(outcome.result).to include("Name")
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just count the newline seperators:

```
expect(outcome.result.split("\n").size).to eq(10)
```

Comment: I think, that `expect(outcome.count("\n")).to eq(10)` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
outcome.lines.count
```

gives you the total number of rows

so `expect(outcome.lines.count).to eq(10)` should help